# How can I write DAX to aggregate total time?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have time format in text as a table in Power bi.

[image: Dataset]

I want to find total duration of time by adding all time together in
days, hours, minutes, seconds

How can I write Dax for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot have more than 23:59:59 in a time column, anything larger does not exist, you would be better converting the elements into days, hours, minutes, seconds. Split by delimiter